# Vg0-root что это?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

Поясните, пожалуйста, что это?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте df -h
Я думаю, там и будет ответ. )

А вообще смотрите LVM, это Linux Volume Manager.

Ну а vg0-root - это устройство / раздела /dev/mapper/VG0-root

Comment: @mak_hash_off, как тут понять что-то? http://c2n.me/3aYsCsv.png

Comment: все очень даже понятно ))) так написано, что /dev/mapper/VG0-root это ваш раздел, размер 208 ГБ, занято 25 ГБ, свободно 173 ГБ, использовано 13%, монтиррован в / - то бишь корень.

Comment: убунту, наверно, да?

Comment: @mak_hash_off, Debian. А почему красным то подсвечивает? :/

Comment: @ModaL наверно, потому что busy 73%, то бишь загружен очень. Вы, видать, что-то куда-то копировали в это время.

Comment: @mak_hash_off, а что могло копироваться, например? Лично я ничего не копировал. :/

Comment: @ModaL, ну, тут я вам не помошник, почему у вас в этот момент шуршал hdd, я ответить не могу, тут слишком много факторов - какая ос стоит, какой софт, что он делает и т.д., может, система обновлялась, может, еще что-то (например, браузер). Вот именно по этой причине я рекомендую использовать gentoo, мало того, что без ведома пользователя ничего не произойдет, так еще и познания в системе даст, чтоб не было подобных вопросов, одна только установка gentoo даст кучу знаний в понимании работы linux.